# Fill a space with a grid from a total amount

Tags: javascript

I want 1000 circles to fill a space. There is a max width. I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem... any help? I feel like this is a very basic algebra.

here is my grid being produced:

```
var WIDTH = 640;
var TOTAL = 1000;
var CIRCLE_SIZE = 5;

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        //draw circles with a radius of CIRCLE_SIZE
        x = j;
        y = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not javascript, javascript doesn't declare datatypes explicitly like `var i:int`

Comment: Sorry I'm prototyping this in something else but I would apply it in javascript. I'll quickly write this in JS.

Comment: Is the size fixed but the total width of the grid not?

Comment: Updated. The total and width of the space is fixed

Comment: Updated to include the two hardcoded vars,

Comment: Sorry but I might of added more info. The circles also have a set size. I just need to fit 1000 of them in a grid based on the width.

Comment: So you need to calculate how many `rows` and `columns` you need right? So `columns =  Math.floor(WIDTH/CIRCLE_SIZE)` then `rows = Math.ceil(TOTAL / columns)` with the caveat that your last row will have fewer circles. Or do you need only full rows?

Comment: Thank you!! I feel like moron and embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of circles that can fit in the width you have you simply need:

```
var columns = Math.floor(WIDTH/CIRCLE_SIZE);
```

With your constants, this gives you `128` columns.

With that you can calculate the number of rows as:

```
var rows = Math.ceil(TOTAL/columns);
```

Which gives you `8` rows. Note however that the last row will have less circles. You can calculate how many with

```
TOTAL % columns
```

Which gives you `104`.